# Make jQuery know when new div is added

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

How could the following code be changed so that the jQuery would know when a new `DIV` is added and it could apply for this newly created `DIV`, too?

The new `DIV` contains an image and is added after image is uploaded.

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( ".divTestImg" ).draggable();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Apply what to this newly created `div`? Where is the code for adding the new `div`?

Comment: **Listening** for these events is not a common approach. But if you insist, I think it has been asked: (stackoverflow.com/questions/9470931/…) But again, it is a more common approach that **you** tell jQuery what to do at the moment when **you** add a new div element. In your case, *after the image is uploaded*. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

When you add the new div, call `.draggable` on it.

```
newDiv.appendTo("body").draggable();
```